# ViewBag Mvc4 with razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm try to make multilingual website using a database, this is part of my code in the controller

```
ViewBag.temp = (from m in db.GIS_SETTING where m.TABLE_NAME == "ID_CARD_TYPES"
     select new { tableName, columnName }).AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

The issue is, I don't know how to use ViewBag inside razor

```
 @Html.Display((string)ViewBag.temp.ID)
```

But it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewBag.temp is a **list** of anonymous types with `tableName` and `columnName`.
You need to enumerate ViewBag.temp in order to get `tableName` and `columnName` from it.